# UK Passport validity dates format

Tags: passports, legal, uk-citizens

The date in my UK passport isn't in the usual format (day, month, year) it shows as-

Date off issue
20 DEC /DEC 10
Date of expiration
20 DEC /DEC 20

bit confusing but I'm guessing it means it expires in Dec 2020..can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Well yes, look at how the dates are labelled. One is for English speakers, the other is in French.  You can also take your passport to one of the Passport Office's publically accessible scanners.

Comment: From 20 December 2010 to 20 December 2020. Although that should really read 19 December 2020.

Comment: @JoErNanO the UK is perfectly justified in issuing passports for ten years and one day if they so choose.  They have so chosen, apparently, so why should the date really read 19 December 2020?

Comment: Imagine the alternative, that the dates are in year/month/day order.  That would mean the passport is valid for eleven days only. To me that seems more than enough evidence to conclude that the order is day/month/year.

Comment: @phoog Seems a bit random to be fair - I wondered whether it might be a half-open range (i.e. the expiry date is the date on which the passport becomes invalid, so validity really is 10 years to the day) but no authoritative references I can find state it clearly either way. Moot I suppose seeing as you usually need like six months of validity to travel anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Croatia also issues passports that expire on the anniversary of issue, for what it's worth, but since it's unusual to get a passport on the day it's printed, the actual useful life of most such passports is going to be slightly less than ten years.  There are dozens of countries at least that can be visited with a UK passport up to the last day of its validity, although the number of such countries is about to be reduced by 26 or 27 (I don't know about Ireland).  The US and Canada are two.

Comment: @phoog Interesting! (and confirmed with a bit of https://uk.usembassy.gov research)

Answer (score 5):

If you're uncertain about the human-readable date, check the expiry field in the machine-readable zone, in which the format is [standardized worldwide](http://www.icao.int/publications/pages/publication.aspx?docnum=9303).

The date of expiry is in character positions 22 through 27 in the second line (immediately after the `M` or `F` that encodes your sex), in YYMMDD format.

Answer (score 3):

"20 DEC/DEC 20" means 20th December, 2020. The repetition is because the month name is given both in English (abbreviating "December") and French ("Décembre"). My own passport, for example, was issued on dd MAY/MAI yy (May/Mai) and expires on dd JUL/JUI yy (July/Juillet).